# options on how to read external data into my ios app

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

ive begun writing an ipad app which will use mapkit to show nearby locations of people offering things for sale ie like property (houses, units etc). i know an individual user can store their own information, data, photos etc on their own device and im intending to incorporate coredata to allow this. What i dont understand are the technologies needed to get "other user's" info, data, property photos etc showing on an individual users device. from my limited knowledge i assume i would need some type of server technology and then send all the information from all current nearby users to each individual user's device so each user can see all the "offerings" of nearby users. what i dont understand is if apple (or anyone else) has provided some frameworks which i can piggy back on to achieve this or whether i'm on my own re learning and developing this. any assistance on best way to start this task is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parse as your backend service . It is free at some point.

Comment: I believe that the 'new' CloudKit API should help you with this. I haven't used it but it seems to allow you specify exactly what parts of a user's data are available for other user's to view, and what parts are not.